# Error message positioning on radio button JQuery Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a radio button where only one should be checked. However the error message was showing on the wrong place, it is showing on the first radio button which is the "walk in". I want it to show under the choices of the radio buttons, under the radio button "under".

Here is my code

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="formApplication" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
       <div class="col-sm-2">
          <input type="radio" name="rbtnFind" id="rbtnWalkIn" value="Walk-In"> Walk-In
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       <div class="col-sm-2">
           <input type="radio" name="rbtnFind" id="rbtnJobFair" value="Job Fair"> Job Fair
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       <div class="col-sm-2">
           <input type="radio" name="rbtnFind" id="rbtnSocialMedia" value="Social Media"> Social Media
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
             <input type="radio" name="rbtnFind" id="rbtnReferred" value="Referred"> Referred
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-2">
              <input type="radio" name="rbtnFind" id="rbtnOther" value="Other"> Other
         </div>
     </div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn pull-right" id="btnContinue1">Continue</button>
  </form>
```

And the JQuery

```
$("#formApplication").submit(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
 }).validate({
     rules:{
        rbtnFind: "required"
     },
     messages: {
        rbtnFind: "Please select an option"
     },
     highlight: function(element){
        if($(element).attr('type') == 'radio'){                       
             $(element.form).find("input[type=radio]").each(function(which){
                 $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
             });
                    } 
        else {
             $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
        }        
     },
     unhighlight: function(element){
         $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
     },
     errorElement: 'span',
     errorClass: 'help-block',
     errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
         if(element.parent('.input-group').length) {
               error.insertAfter(element.parent());
         } else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
         }
      },
      submitHandler: function(form) { 
           //submit code         
      }
      });
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/19sksaex/) is the code in JSFiddle.

Comment: I don't see any error messages.

Comment: __However the error message was showing on the wrong place__
is there any relation between your question and title?

Comment: I forgot to change the title, I was having a different error a while ago. I'll change it.

Comment: can't reproduce the issue. add your full code

Comment: The code is in the link I have given in JSFiddle. Here it is anyway: https://jsfiddle.net/19sksaex/

Comment: where you want to show your error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here my Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/skyr9999/8nm3tvph/ i hope it helps you, i made changes in js and add placeholder to html:

```
$("#formApplication").submit(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
 }).validate({
     rules:{
        rbtnFind: "required"
     },
     messages: {
        rbtnFind: "Please select an option"
     },
     highlight: function(element){
        if($(element).attr('type') == 'radio'){                       
             $(element.form).find("input[type=radio]").each(function(which){
                 $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
             });
                    } 
        else {
             $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
        }        
     },
     unhighlight: function(element){
         $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
     },
     errorElement: 'span',
     errorClass: 'help-block',
     errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        $(".error_placeholder").html(error.html());
      },
        submitHandler: function(form) { 
        $(".error_placeholder").html("");
           //submit code         
      }
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#formApplication").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}).validate({
  rules: {
    rbtnFind: "required"
  },
  messages: {
    rbtnFind: "Please select an option"
  },
  highlight: function(element) {
    if ($(element).attr('type') == 'radio') {
      $(element.form).find("input[type=radio]").each(function(which) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
      });
    } else {
      $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    }

    //$(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
  },
  unhighlight: function(element) {
    $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
  },
  errorElement: 'span',
  errorClass: 'help-block',
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    if (element.parent('.input-group').length) {
     error.insertAfter(element.parent());
    } else {
    console.log(error);
      error.insertAfter('.has-error'); //Replace has-error with element
    }
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes to your script, see if you want it that way

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="formApplication" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <input type="radio" name="rbtnFind" id="rbtnWalkIn" value="Walk-In"> Walk-In
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <input type="radio" name="rbtnFind" id="rbtnJobFair" value="Job Fair"> Job Fair
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <input type="radio" name="rbtnFind" id="rbtnSocialMedia" value="Social Media"> Social Media
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <input type="radio" name="rbtnFind" id="rbtnReferred" value="Referred"> Referred
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <input type="radio" class="errorPlacement" name="rbtnFind" id="rbtnOther" value="Other"> Other
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="divFindFollowUp" class="form-group">
    <!-- For the follow up for the question above -->
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn pull-right" id="btnContinue1">Continue</button>
</form>
<script>
    $("#formApplication").submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }).validate({
      rules: {
        rbtnFind: "required"
      },
      messages: {
        rbtnFind: "Please select an option"
      },
      highlight: function(element) {
        if ($(element).attr('type') == 'radio') {
        $(element.form).find("input[type=radio]").last().closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
        } else {
          $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
        }

        //$(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
      },
      unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
      },
      errorElement: 'span',
      errorClass: 'help-block',
      errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      if ($(element).attr('type') == 'radio') {
        error.insertAfter($(".errorPlacement").parent());
      }
      else{
        if (element.parent('.input-group').length) {
          error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        } else {
          error.insertAfter(element);
        }
      }
      },
      submitHandler: function(form) {

      }
    });
</script>
```